# Error: No named parameter with the name 'selectableDayPredicate'

Tags: flutter, dart

My code was working great until a few days ago. I get this error. My code is like that

```
FormBuilderDateRangePicker(
    onChanged: (val) => onEditing(val),
    selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) => val.isAfter(DateTime.now()) ? false : true,//here it throws the error
    autofocus: true,
    locale: Locale(_myLocale),
    name: "choose_date_range",
    firstDate: DateTime(2017),
    lastDate: DateTime( DateTime.now().year+1),
    format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    ...
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you share this class? FormBuilderDateRangePicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parameters for the **[FormBuilderDateTimePicker](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderDateTimePicker-class.html)** class but calling **[FormBuilderDateRangePicker](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_form_builder/latest/flutter_form_builder/FormBuilderDateRangePicker-class.html)** class

Comment: selectableDayPredicate was working for FormBuilderDateRangePicker also, what changed?

Comment: Can you prohibit the user from choosing future dates in FormBuilderDateRangePicker, just like selectDayPredicate does?

Comment: Cant answer that. Did you upgrated your packages? The lastDate parameters does not prevent it?

Comment: lastDate parameter disable it only if you set it to DateTime.now(), not exactly what I wanted but it works. Thanks!

Comment: I think you could use an controller to pick the chosen date and adjust it to the maximum date allowed